# Is there any way to know the numbers which are NOT a term in a particular arithmetic progression??

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, arithmetic

For example say: 5n+2, 5=d, n = x-1 (for any x), a = 2. So, we can know that 3,5,8, etc. are definitely not terms in this progression, by hit and trial. But, is there any direct way by which can represent the terms which are NOT any term in the Arithmetic Progression?? The particular progression I'm looking for is:

3n+1 + (x-1)(2n+1). I want to know the numbers which are not a part of this progression. Thank you.

This is my first time posting here, please bare with me and spare me for my naivety.

Comment: Really Sorry. That was a typing mistake, I meant a (first term) = 2.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I'm not entirely certain I understand your question as phrased. Your typical arithmetic progression is $T_n = an + d$, where $n$ is any non-negative integer, and $d$ is the first term (that is, $T_0 = d$). I'm unclear which part of your expression is meant to be the "progressing" part, that is, the $n$ I've described, and which parts are meant to be equivalent to $a$ and $d$. Is $3n +1$ supposed to be the first term?  Also--is the relationship $n = x-1$ intended to hold in your expression? Because I don't think it's an arithmetic progression at that point.

Comment: Yes, a(the first term) is 3n+1. d(common difference) is 2n+1. While, (x-1) is supposed to be (n-1) in the generalised form of the Arithmetic Progression - a+(n-1)d. So, I want to know which numbers exactly don't come I.e. are not a  term of this particular A.P.:         3n+1 + (x-1)(2n+1), where both n and x belong to Natural Numbers.

Comment: The terms not in an AP belong to other AP. For instance, the even are not the odd numbers: Numbers not in 2n+1 are in 2n+2. Similarly, numbers not in 3n+1 are either in 3n+2 or in 3n+3.

Comment: You could say $n \not \equiv 2 \pmod 5$

Answer (score 2):

One way to check if a progression of terms $T_n$ contains a particular term $T$ is to equate $T_n = T$ and solve for $n$. If you get a positive integer, you know the term $T$ will occur in the sequence $T_n$ in the usual (forward) direction. If you get $n$ as an integer such that $n \leq 0$, you know that extension of the sequence in the other (reverse) direction will yield that term. But if $n$ is not an integer at all, you know that the term won't occur in the sequence at all.

Answer (score 0):

OK, given your response to my question, I *think* what you're asking is better rephrased like this:

Consider the arithmetic progression $a_x = a_1 + (x-1)d$, for $x \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Define the progression using $a_1 = 3n + 1$ and $d = 2n + 1$. We can write an infinite number of progressions for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Define $A_n$ as the set of numbers in the progression for each $n$. Then $A$ is the union of all of those sets--the integers whose values *are* part of at least of of the progressions. Now we ask: what is left if we remove $A$ from $\mathbb{Z}^+$ ?

(I specified positive integers because if we allow $n = 0$, then the progression is the trivial $1 + (x-1) \cdot 1$, which is simply all of the non-negative integers.)

I like to just look at the first few possible values to get a feel for things. For $ n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ we have

$$ A_1 = \{4,7,10,13, 16...\} \\ 
A_2 = \{7, 12, 17, 22, 27...\} \\ 
A_3 = \{10, 17, 24, 31, 38...\} \\
A_4 = \{13, 22, 31, 40, 49...\} \\
A_5 = \{16, 27, 38, 49, 60...\}$$

Huh. There's a quite pleasing symmetry in there! In all cases, $a_x$ in $A_n$ is also $a_n$ in $A_x$! Maybe we can use that to our advantage later.

What else can we see in here? Well, all of these progressions increase by odd numbers, which makes sense, because since $2n + 1$ is always odd. But that means every one of these numbers has to be the sum of $4$ and some subset of the odd numbers $2n + 1 \geq 3$. Hey hey hey, now we're getting somewhere. In fact, we could probably stop here if we wanted, and say "All numbers not expressible as the sum of 4 and some list of odd numbers (not necessarily different) cannot be part of any of these progressions." Maybe. But is that right?

Well, I don't see $9$ anywhere up there, so we can't add just $4+5$. There must be some boundaries to what we can do. Let's collect some terms, though, to make some things easier. If we have added $m$ odd numbers to $4$, we can say that all the values in $A$ must be:

$$a = 4 + (2k_1 +1) + (2k_2 + 1) + \cdots + (2k_m +1) = 4+ 2\sum k_i+m = 4 + 2K + m$$

Where $K$ is just the sum of the sequence $k_n$, and the sequence has length $m$. Let's make that initial evaluation of the sets into a diagram, taking advantage of symmetry to use just a triangle:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
4 @>1>>7@>1>>10@>1>>13@>1>>16@>1>>19\\
@.@VV2V@VV3V@VV4V@VV5V@VV6V\\
@.12@>>2>17@>>2>22@>>2>27@>>2>32\\
@.@.@VV3V@VV4V@VV5V@VV6V\\
@.@.24@>>3>31@>>3>38@>>3>45\\
@.@.@.@VV4V@VV5V@VV6V\\
@.@.@.40@>>4>49@>>4>58\\
@.@.@.@.@VV5V@VV6V\\
@.@.@.@.60@>>5>71\\
@.@.@.@.@.@VV6V\\
@.@.@.@.@.80\\
\end{CD}

Whoa-hoa-hoakay, that looks complex. But it's not, really. The main numbers are what we had before, though I extended it on the right. The arrows are the "moves" we can make to get to another number, and the number on each arrow is a $k$. Each "move" adds $2k_i +1$.
Note that every row and column of arrows has the same $k_i$ as all the others in that row or column.

Now we can decide on $m$, and see what possible sequences of moves are available.

For $m = 0$, well that's just zero moves, not interesting.
For $m = 1$, we only have one choice: $k_1 = 1$.
For $m = 2$, we start having choices. Our sequence can be $(1,1)$ or $(1,2)$. Let's look at the next few values of $m$:

$$\begin{array}{cccccccc}
m=3& (1,1,1) & (1,2,2) & (1,1,3) \\
m = 4 & (1,1,1,1) & (1,1,1,4) & (1,2,2,2) & (1,2,2,3) & (1,1,3,2) & (1,1,3,3) \\
\end{array}$$

Well that'll get big really fast. But we can get something from it. For $m = 1, K = 1$. For $m = 2, K \in \{2,3\}$. For $m = 3, K \in \{3,5\}$, and for $m = 4, K \in \{4,7,8\}$.

And now... I'm going to leave you hanging just a bit. Figure out for yourself what values of $K$ are allowed for the next few values of $m$, up to maybe $m=7$ or $8$ (because typing them here will take a long time). You'll have to extend the diagram to the right once or twice. Then look for the pattern. And there *is* a pattern!

(Hint: you'll need another variable, I called mine $i$, and you'll end up writing K in terms of $i$ and $m$. The possible values of $i$ are limited by $m$ in some way.)

I'll come back in a couple of days in hopes you'll find the pattern!

---

Alas, you didn't come back to comment... but here is the remainder of the solution:

If you look at the numbers that pop out for various values of $m$, two values are always there: $m$ itself and $2m-1$. Then we see other initially random-appearing values, like $2m$ for $m=4$. But wait... $2m = 3m - 4$ when $m=4$. Could there be something here dealing with squares? $m=4$ has $4,7,8$ available. $7 = 4m - 9$... and $4 = 5m - 16$, even!

If we consider each of these cases separately, what we find is that for $1 \leq i \leq m+1$, we can write $K = im - (i-1)^2$. That means we can take our old friend $a = 4 +2K + m$ and rewrite:

$$a = 4 + 2\left(im - (i-1)^2\right) -m \\
a = 2+m+4i+2mi-2i^2$$

For $m \geq 0$ and $m+1 \geq i \geq 1$. The $m+1$ in the last constraint allows us to use $m = 0, i = 1$ to get the original $4$.

So: all numbers not expressible in this form are not in the progression.

Comment: Thank you very much, for helping me out so much. I'm really sorry that I was not able to reply to you earlier. This is something I wouldn't have been able to do on my own. I like the result which we have reached at the end, quite distinct.

Comment: Also, is there any way to generalize the numbers that don't fall under this progression, in any distinct manner.

Comment: The only real way to generalize those numbers (that I can see) is to say they're the numbers not in the set. I could be wrong.

Comment: But, aren't the numbers which are not part of a particular arithmetic progression, essentially a part of another arithmetic progression (at least when all the numbers are considered). So, the numbers which are not a part of this, should also such symmetry.

Comment: Not necessarily! As a simple case, just consider the arithmetic progression $a_n = 5n + 2$, that is, $2,7,12,17...$ There's no single arithmetic progression that contains all the absent numbers--you have to define at least four. If you're familiar with modular arithmetic, you could indicate that the absent numbers are all integers where $n \not \equiv 2 \pmod 5$, but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: (Or, considered in a different light, converting "all numbers not of the form [expression]" into "all numbers of the form [different expression]" is really, really hard!)

Comment: Yes, I have worked upon the problem more and now I'm representing those numbers (which are not part of any progression) as $2^x+n$ .Why?? Because in the end the arithmetic progression is gonna get equal to 2mn+m+n. How?? This is the A.P. =     3n+1 + (x-1)(2n+1) = 3n+1+2nx+x-2n-1=n+x+2nx = 2mn+m+n, (m=x). Now, 2mn+m+n can be written as (2mn+m)+n = (2n+1)m +n. The numbers that are not a part of the progression would not be equal to 2mn+m+n. Similarly, $2^x$ can never be (2n+1)m, so using that as the frame of reference, we're representing those numbers. I suggest you read the question here.

Comment: [link to the question = $2^x+n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4035061/can-there-be-a-generalization-for-n-in-the-equation-2x-a-n)

Comment: Huh. $2nx + n + x$ is certainly simpler than what I got to, through an easier route! But while you're correct that $(2n+1)m$ can never be equal to some $2^k$, there are more excluded values of $(2n+1)m$ than those of the form $2^k$, because the values are partially determined by $n$. So, yes, no integer $2^k$ can be written in the form $(2n+1)m$ with $n=1$, but neither can any non-multiple of $3$. Similarly, if $n=2$, no non-multiple of $5$ can be written as $(2n+1)m$. But there may be some kernel of something useful in there; I'll continue to ponder.

Comment: After ruminating on this, I think it comes down to there not being a closed-form expression for the complement of a set defined by an algebraic expression. The example that came to mind is this: the set $K=\{k \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \mid k = 6ab\pm a\pm b, b\geq a\geq 1 \land a, b\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}$. This is actually pretty similar to the equation for your set, i.e. $2mn+m+n$. The set $K$ is the set of positive integers for which $6k\pm 1$ are *not* twin primes. If you could write the complement of that set with an algebraic expression, well, you've solved the TPC, claim your Fields Medal.

Comment: ...but if it were that easy, someone would have figured it out quite a while ago. I'll be so bold as to conjecture that it's impossible to find a closed-form algebraic expression for the complement of any set defined by the solutions of $f(x,y) = axy \pm bx \pm cy$, where $a, b, c$ are positive integers not all equal to each other, and the domain and range of $f(x,y)$ is $\mathbb{Z}+ \times \mathbb{Z}+$. I don't think it's doable.

Comment: Yes, you're right and at first, I also had tried to represent primes as 6n±1, as this is the general form of all primes, but then abandoned and instead used a more-general 2n+1, as in 6n±1, we would have sign changes and at least 3 different equations for odd composite numbers = (6n+1)(6n+1), (6n-1)(6n-1), (6n+1)(6n-1). Also, I was not getting any particular seclusion for even bases like we have $2^x$ in the system of 2n+1.

Comment: (To your 3rd comment), yes, I understand that if it were that easy, someone should have done it, but then should we just abandon it?? Rather, I say we can think more, maybe there's more to the picture than it seems... Also my point in using $2^x$ is that we link primes to the exponential values of 2. i.e. I say in 2a+1, where a≠2mn+m+n (in primes), we write $a=2^x+n$ and generalize for n (as I said in the other question). Writing the full expression gives us $2^{x+1} + 2n+1 = 2a+1$ (prime). That is in short some odd number (2n+1) added to $2^x$. Also, btw, thank you very much for helping me.