# Can there be a generalization for n in the equation $2^x = a-n$??

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic, generating-functions

This might seem a vague question, but let me give you its background before going on.
I have obtained an equation where a=2mn+m+n, where all a,n and m are natural numbers and neither 'm' or 'n' or both of them can be equal to 0 (0 is not a natural number, but a whole number).

Not all values of a i.e. the natural numbers satisfy 2mn+m+n and these are the numbers that I need to find (i.e. the values for 'a' which don't satisfy $2mn+m+m$).

For this, I see that 2mn+m+n can be written as $(2mn+m) + n = (2n+1)m + n$.
All the numbers can be represented as (2n+1)m except for $2^x$.
This is because, in $(2n+1)m$, $2n+1$ is an odd number, i.e. all the odd numbers can written as such.
Similarly, only those even numbers whose prime factorization consists purely of even numbers i.e. 2, CANNOT be written in this form i.e. $2^x$ numbers.

We have some values for 'a' which are not equal to 2mn+m+n and we're looking to find those.
Similarly, we see that (2n+1)m also CANNOT be written as $2^x$.

Thus, $a ≠ 2mn+m+n$, $2^x ≠ (2n+1)m$  i.e. $2mn+m$.

Therefore, $2^x+n≠ 2mn+m+n$ (the inequality is maintained here),
$2^x+n ≠ a$

Now, a is not alone but, itself is a part of the equation $2a+1$, where 'a' CAN be represented as
2mn+m+n, i.e. '2a+1' is an odd composite number, as in $2a+1$, a can be written as 2mn+m+n, how??
$(2n+1)(2m+1) = 4mn+2m+2n+1 = 2(2mn+m+n)+1$, while the values for a which don't satisfy $2mn+m+n$, $2a+1$ is a
prime number.

Therefore, $a ≠ 2^x+n$. Similarly, $2a+1 ≠ 2(2^x+n)+1$ (again, inequality is maintained).

$2^{x+1} + 2n+1≠2a+1$.
Thus, $2^{x+1} ≠ 2a-2n$,

$2^{x+1} ≠ 2(a-n)$,

$2^x≠a-n$, where 'a' can be represented as 2mn+m+n.

i.e. $2^x≠2mn+m+n-n$,

giving us,
$2^x≠2mn+m$,
$2^x≠(2n+1)m$

And, where 'a' CANNOT be represented as $2mn+m+n$, (i.e. where $2a+1$ is prime)

$2^x=a-n$

$2^x$ is given, and there is a pre requisite condition for $a$.
So, my question -
Is there any way to generalize the values for $n$??

Comment: This post appears to be exactly the same as [Can there be a generalization for n in the equation $2^x=a−n$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/384802/129887) posted on MathOverflow about a day ago. As I wrote in a comment there, please wait considerable longer, with some discussions I've seen suggesting a minimum of a week, before even considering posting there after posting here without a satisfactory answer. Also, if you do cross-post, then always include links from each post to the other one to at least help reduce, and ideally avoid, duplication of efforts among the members.

Comment: Very Sorry, I wasn't aware that reposting is not allowed, at least when the same member posts it. Time is not a worry for me, but it's only that I have got a meeting with an institutional director on Saturday and I want to present this to him, so that is why I'm in a little hurry and wanted some response from the people.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to do this would be to consider the equivalent equation $$2a+1=(2m+1)(2n+1).$$ It means that the odd number $2a+1$ can't have any non-trivial (i.e. different from $1$ or itself) odd divisors, meaning it must be an odd prime number.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand what this adds to the already existing notion of a prime-number.  Values of a where it is not equal to 2mn+m+n and representing it as an addition with 2^x is different as 2^x is unique and quite specific here. Say, if we do get a generalization for n, then it gets a lot simpler. While $2a+1 = (2m+1)(2n+1)$ is basically just the general form of all odd composite odd numbers.

Comment: This "answer" adds nothing to the discussion above. Your equation was considered by the OP, and was included in their question body.

Comment: @player3236 Your "comment" missed the fact that the question was edited *after* I posted my answer, just look at the time stamps and the edit history of the question.

Comment: Check the original. The edit was purely LaTeX.